# Namespace issue with wcf Restful service

Tags: wcf, namespaces, wcf-rest

This is my first post.
I am building  a restful wcf service using post to accept an XML message (truncated from the real one). I am having trouble getting WCF to parse the XML due to the way the message is using namespaces. I cannot change the format of the XML message.
I have tried various combinations of namespace attributes on the Service and datacontract but either get a parsing error or segments that are missing or NULL.
If I was able to change the message I can get it to work by either removing the namespace or by applying the namespace prefix to all the fields. Unfortunately, it is not possible to get the vendor to change the format of the message being sent.

Is there a way to get this to work with the message being sent.

Sample Request

```
   <m:MYMESSAGE xmlns:m="my.report">
        <MESSAGEHEADER>
            <MESSAGETYPE>GoodReport</MESSAGETYPE>
            <MESSAGEDATE>20160203134445</MESSAGEDATE>
            <MESSAGEACTION>UPDATE</MESSAGEACTION>
        </MESSAGEHEADER>
        <PATIENT>
            <LASTNAME>Last</LASTNAME>
            <FIRSTNAME>First</FIRSTNAME>
            <MIDDLENAME>Middlename</MIDDLENAME>
        </PATIENT>
    </m:MYMESSAGE>
```

Sample Incorrect Response

```
<MYMESSAGE xmlns="my.report" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <MESSAGEHEADER i:nil="true"/>
   <PATIENT i:nil="true"/>
 </MYMESSAGE>
```

WCF Code

```
  [ServiceContract]
    public interface IPDF
    {
        [OperationContract ]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml
           )]
        MYMESSAGE GetPdf(MYMESSAGE mymessage);

    }

  [DataContract(Name = "MYMESSAGE", Namespace = "my.report")]
        public class MYMESSAGE
        {
            [DataMember (Name ="MESSAGEHEADER",Order=0)  ]
            public _MESSAGEHEADER MESSAGEHEADER { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "PATIENT", Order = 1)]
            public _PATIENT PATIENT { get; set; }

        }

        [DataContract(Namespace = "my.report")]
        public class _MESSAGEHEADER
        {
            [DataMember(Name = "MESSAGETYPE", Order = 0)]
            public string MESSAGETYPE { get; set; }
            [DataMember(Name = "MESSAGEDATE", Order = 1)]
            public string MESSAGEDATE { get; set; }


          }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Message Contracts](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730255.aspx) to create the shape of the message you need. For eaxample:

```
[MessageContract]
public class BankingTransaction
{
  [MessageHeader] public Operation operation;
  [MessageHeader(Namespace="http://schemas.contoso.com/auditing/2005")] public bool IsAudited;
  [MessageBodyMember(Name="transactionData")] public BankingTransactionData theData;
})
```

WCF uses Message based on SOAP but WCF internals can hide this by converting inbound messages to SOAP and outbound messages to what ever transport protocol you are using.

You can ultimately create your own [message formatter](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/carlosfigueira/2011/05/02/wcf-extensibility-message-formatters/).

"Message formatters are the component which do the translation between CLR operations and the WCF Message object – their role is to convert all the operation parameters and return values (possibly via serialization) into a Message on output, and deconstruct the message into parameter and return values on input."

Comment: I tried out the MessageContract but no luck so far. I can put a Namespace on the Service Contract but the MessageBodyMemeber doesn't seem to have its own namespace attribute. I get this for a response.

`<MYMESSAGE xmlns="my.report">
   <MESSAGEHEADER i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
   <PATIENT i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
   <ATTACHMENT i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
   <CONTENT i:nil="true" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"/>
</MYMESSAGE>`

Comment: Is MessageContract supported for RESTFUL services? It seems more SOAP oriented.